# EC2 instance in a public subnet has no public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've launched an EC2 instance in a public subnet, but the instance has no public IP.

What could be the reason?

Sorry for the short question, I just don't know what other information is relevant. Please let me know if any further information is required and I will provide that.

I've been googling it for a while and hasn't found the answer yet.

Comment: Is it a public subnet in a custom VPC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the instance will gain a public IP only if the subnet setting is to auto assign a public IP.

Without this in place you would need to ensure you set this during instance creation to assign the public IP to the instance.

A public subnet is generally how we refer to the subnet, but ultimately it is simply a subnet in a VPC with a route to the public internet via an internet gateway. By enabling this setting on your subnet you will not need to specify each time whether you want a public IP to be assigned.

Take a look at the following for more information:

- [Modifying the public IPv4 addressing attribute for your subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-public-ip)
- [Assigning a public IPv4 address during instance launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip)